# DBUnit : Setting properties from maven

Tags: java, maven

To use DBunit, some properties has to be set. They can be set directly through the code, or through maven properties.

I'm using DBunit 2.4.9, and I have troubles settings it through maven. I've checked the pom.xml from DBunit, and this is present :

```
<systemProperties>
        ....
        <property>
          <name>dbunit.profile.driverClass</name>
          <value>${dbunit.profile.driverClass}</value>
        </property>
```

I've tried to set this property from settings.xml or the project pom.xml, but I still get this exception :  `DbAssertionFailedError: driverClass is null`

Here are properties that I set on my pom.xml (at the root level) :

```
<properties>
    <dbunit.profile.driverClass>org.postgresql.Driver</dbunit.profile.driverClass>
    <dbunit.profile.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tests</dbunit.profile.url>
    <dbunit.profile.user>postgres</dbunit.profile.user>
    <dbunit.profile.password>postgres</dbunit.profile.password>
/properties>
```

I'm quite new to maven, so I think i'm missing something here

Comment: I think, defining this kind of properties in pom.xml is far better than settings.xml. Could you post your pom.xml that you tried to set `dbunit.profile.driverClass` property? Also, could you execute your maven command with `-X` (in debug mode), and post the result?

Comment: I've had the properties section of the pom.xml to the original post. For maven logs, I've pasted the maven logs here : http://paste.ubuntu.com/11973895/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. The problem came from properties name that are not between the POM.xml et the actual code. 
For instance, the code relies on the property `dbunit.driverClass` and the DBunit POM.xml contains the following lines inside of the properties :

```
<property>
  <name>dbunit.profile.driverClass</name>
  <value>${dbunit.profile.driverClass}</value>
</property>
```

I had the following configuration to the `maven-failsafe-plugin` :

```
<configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <dbunit.driverClass>${dbunit.profile.driverClass}</dbunit.driverClass>
        <dbunit.connectionUrl>${dbunit.profile.url}</dbunit.connectionUrl>
        <dbunit.username>${dbunit.profile.user}</dbunit.username>
        <dbunit.password>${dbunit.profile.password}</dbunit.password>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
```

If you have a better way to solve it i'm open to suggestions